# Views not displaying correctly in iOS 4.3 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabbar, ios4

I am working on an app which requires that the user be logged in at all times. Initially it has a login view, and when the user is logged in this is replaced with a tabbar view. If I build to either my device (iOS 5.0) or to the 5.0 simulator it works fine. However if I build to the 4.3 simulator I get strange problems.

For instance: the first tab that it opens onto originally contained the login view - I haven't got round to removing it yet so at the moment as soon as that tab opens it fades from a login view to a menu screen (both are separate views within the first tab). In iOS4.3 builds this first view does not fade out.

I recoded it to skip past the first screen and have the first tab open directly into the menu screen which has the users Facebook friends list. I have printed the friends list to the console and it is received correctly - yet the list appears empty in iOS4.3 and works fine in iOS 5.0.
These things all worked until I implemented the separate login view (afaik). I'm presuming that I have not implemented the change between views correctly but I'm not sure where it is wrong as I do not get any errors printed to the console, and I can still change between tabs etc.

This is how I have done it so far (I'll only include relevant parts):

```
appDelegate.h
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UITabBarControllerDelegate,LoginViewControllerDelegate, otherDelegates>

 FirstViewController *viewController1;
SecondViewController *viewController2;
ThirdViewController *viewController3;
FourthViewController *viewController4;
FifthViewController *viewController5;
loginViewController *lvc;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

...

```
appDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
lvc = [[loginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:nil];
lvc.delegate = self;
[self.window addSubview:lvc.view];
self.window.rootViewController = lvc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}



- (void)loginViewControllerDidFinish:(loginViewController *)loginViewController {

//load windows and tab bar controller
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewiPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController4 = [[[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewiPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
viewController5 = [[[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewiPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[viewController4 updateTabBar];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, viewController5, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


//called when logout button is pressed
- (void)removeTabBarView
{
//[self.tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.window addSubview:lvc.view];
self.window.rootViewController = lvc;
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Edit: this is called in the appDelegate once all of the login data has been received.

```
[self loginViewControllerDidFinish:lvc];
```

The fact it works fine in iOS 5.0 is what's really throwing me, I'm pretty new to app development so I have no idea how this could be done differently.
If anyone has any ideas I would be very appreciative.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual I spent ages looking at it, gave up and decided to ask for help, and then realised a way to do it about half an hour later.

I just put this after I setup the tabbar and set it as the view controller (i.e. put the login view on top):

```
lvc = [[loginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginViewController" bundle:nil];
lvc.delegate = self;
[self.window addSubview:lvc.view];
```

Then I just use:

```
[lvc.view removeFromSuperview];
```

to remove it once I'm logged in. Still don't know why the other way didn't work in iOS 4.3 though, so if anyone can provide an answer to that I'll still mark a correct answer - in case anyone else has the same problem in future.